# How many times a string containes in substring - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array:

```
var textWord = [ 'FORTWO', 'ELECTRIC' ];
```

and a json object:

```
var modelsList = {
    'FOR FOUR' : null,
    'FOR FOUR DIESEL' : null,
    'FOR FOUR EV' : null,
    'FORTWO CABRIO ELECTRIC DRIVE' : null,
    'FORTWO Cabrio' : null,
    'FORTWO Cabrio Diesel' : null,
    'FORTWO Coupe' : null,
    'FORTWO Coupe Diesel' : null,
    'ROADSTER' : null,
    'ROADSTER Coupe' : null,
}
```

I want to find how many times find the word of array into json object. The null of object represent the times it was found.
My code is:

```
var textWord = [ 'FORTWO', 'ELECTRIC' ];
var modelsList = {
    'FOR FOUR' : null,
    'FOR FOUR DIESEL' : null,
    'FOR FOUR EV' : null,
    'FORTWO CABRIO ELECTRIC DRIVE' : null,
    'FORTWO Cabrio' : null,
    'FORTWO Cabrio Diesel' : null,
    'FORTWO Coupe' : null,
    'FORTWO Coupe Diesel' : null,
    'ROADSTER' : null,
    'ROADSTER Coupe' : null,
}
var counter = 0;
 for(let i=0; i < textWord.length; i++){
    for (let modelsListText in modelsList) {
        if (modelsListText.toUpperCase().includes(textWord[i].toUpperCase())) {
            modelsList[modelsListText] = counter++;
        }
    }
}
console.log(modelsList);
```

The result is:

```
{
  'FOR FOUR': null,
  'FOR FOUR DIESEL': null,
  'FOR FOUR EV': null,
  'FORTWO CABRIO ELECTRIC DRIVE': 5,
  'FORTWO Cabrio': 1,
  'FORTWO Cabrio Diesel': 2,
  'FORTWO Coupe': 3,
  'FORTWO Coupe Diesel': 4,
  ROADSTER: null,
  'ROADSTER Coupe': null
}
```

But the result I want to get is:

```
{
  'FOR FOUR': null,
  'FOR FOUR DIESEL': null,
  'FOR FOUR EV': null,
  'FORTWO CABRIO ELECTRIC DRIVE': 2, //Match and FORTWO and ELECTRIC
  'FORTWO Cabrio': 1, //Match ONLY FORTWO
  'FORTWO Cabrio Diesel': 1, //Match ONLY FORTWO
  'FORTWO Coupe': 1, //Match ONLY FORTWO
  'FORTWO Coupe Diesel': 1, //Match ONLY FORTWO
  ROADSTER: null,
  'ROADSTER Coupe': null
}
```

Comment: Don't abuse `.toUpperCase()` to perform case-insensitive string comparisons. Instead use the `i` regex flag with `String.prototype.match`.

Comment: Change your `modelsList` from a JavaScript `object` to a `Map` object: that way you won't run into unintentional key/property-name conflicts. (Also, `modelsList` _is not a list_, so don't call it that, I'd rename it to something like `modelsCounts` or similar, and use `0` instead of `null` as the default value, methinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for current value at that time, If there is a value other than `null` then you can `increment` it else put `1` inplace of current value

Either use this

```
modelsList[modelsListText] = (modelsList[modelsListText] ?? 0) + 1;
```

or

```
modelsList[modelsListText] = modelsList[modelsListText]
                ? modelsList[modelsListText] + 1
                : 1;
```

```js
var textWord = ['FORTWO', 'ELECTRIC'];
var modelsList = {
    'FOR FOUR': null,
    'FOR FOUR DIESEL': null,
    'FOR FOUR EV': null,
    'FORTWO CABRIO ELECTRIC DRIVE': null,
    'FORTWO Cabrio': null,
    'FORTWO Cabrio Diesel': null,
    'FORTWO Coupe': null,
    'FORTWO Coupe Diesel': null,
    ROADSTER: null,
    'ROADSTER Coupe': null,
};

for (let i = 0; i < textWord.length; i++) {
    for (let modelsListText in modelsList) {
        if (modelsListText.toUpperCase().includes(textWord[i].toUpperCase())) {
            modelsList[modelsListText] = modelsList[modelsListText]
                ? modelsList[modelsListText] + 1
                : 1;
        }
    }
}

console.log(modelsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to remove the need for nested loops.

[`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) your `textWord` array with an `|` (which means "or") so the regex looks like `/FORTWO|ELECTRIC/g`, and use that to [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on each key of the object. If a match is made check the length of the array that `match` returns and update the value of that key's value with that number.

```js
const textWord=['FORTWO','ELECTRIC'];
const modelsList={'FOR FOUR':null,'FOR FOUR DIESEL':null,'FOR FOUR EV':null,'FORTWO CABRIO ELECTRIC DRIVE':null,'FORTWO Cabrio':null,'FORTWO Cabrio Diesel':null,'FORTWO Coupe':null,'FORTWO Coupe Diesel':null,ROADSTER:null,'ROADSTER Coupe':null};

const re = new RegExp(textWord.join('|'), 'g');

for (const prop in modelsList) {
  const match = prop.match(re);
  if (match) modelsList[prop] = match.length;
}

console.log(modelsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to perform a case-insensitive search, that's why you are using the `toUpperCase`. Either way, this should work.

```js
var textWord = ['FORTWO', 'ELECTRIC'];
var modelsList = {
    'FOR FOUR': null,
    'FOR FOUR DIESEL': null,
    'FOR FOUR EV': null,
    'FORTWO CABRIO ELECTRIC DRIVE': null,
    'FORTWO Cabrio': null,
    'FORTWO Cabrio Diesel': null,
    'FORTWO Coupe': null,
    'FORTWO Coupe Diesel': null,
    'ROADSTER': null,
    'ROADSTER Coupe': null,
}

for (let modelsListText in modelsList) {
    var counter = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < textWord.length; i++) {
        if (modelsListText.toUpperCase().includes(textWord[i].toUpperCase())) {
            counter++
            modelsList[modelsListText] = counter
        }
    }
}

console.log(modelsList);
```

The major difference is where the counter is first declared. You want to reset the counter for each new `modelsList` item you want to search through.